# How can I get the number of rows 'returned' from a result set of a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get the number of rows 'returned' from a stored procedure?
I know the result set is not really returned so I can't select from it or count on it.
I tried to use an out parameter but with no success..

Basically I have some logic in the stored procedure that finds some table lines. I use it in my C# app. in another place I need the exact same logic but only the count so I will be able to use in an SQL statement.

I could bring it to the C# and count there but I prefer not.
I could also create a stored function that duplicate the logic but returns COUNT but I prefer not to duplicate so I don't maintain it twice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This 
found_rows function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: It's not the perfect solution for me but I can use it (design issues). Thanks!!

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS example name FROM tablename
```

Comment: I don't see that this answers the question asked.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.